# What's the proper way to create these tables?

Tags: sql-server

I'm reverse engineering a script that creates a payroll database from my textbook. I'm rebuilding it into a library management system instead. To start I've drawn out a diagram of the tables/columns and their relationships [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ54c.jpg). Now following the script from the textbook I use the authors technique to create all the tables except for the **BooksIssued** table and **InvoiceItems** table. This is my code

```
USE master
GO

/******Check to see if database exists******/
IF DB_ID('SET2133810') IS NOT NULL
    DROP DATABASE SET2133810
GO

/******Object: Database SET2133810******/
CREATE DATABASE SET2133810
GO

USE SET2133810
GO

/******Object: table*****/
CREATE TABLE VendorsList(
    VendorID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    VendorName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    VendorPhone varchar(50) NULL,
    VendorContactLName varchar(50) NULL,
    VendorContactFName varchar(50) NULL,
    VendorAddress varchar(50) NULL,
    VendorCity varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    VendorState char(2) NOT NULL,
    VendorZipCode varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_VendorsList PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    VendorID ASC
 )
)
GO

/******Object: Table*****/
CREATE TABLE InvoicesList(
    InvoiceID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    VendorID int NOT NULL,
    InvoiceNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    InvoiceDate smalldatetime NOT NULL,
    InvoiceTotal money NOT NULL,
    PaymentTotal money NOT NULL,
    PaymentDate smalldatetime NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_InvoicesList PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(
    InvoiceID ASC
 )
)
GO

/******Object: Table*****/
CREATE TABLE BookList(
    BookID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    BookISBN varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    BookTitle varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    BookAuthor varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    BookPublisher varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    BookGenre varchar(50) NULL
 CONSTRAINT PK_BookList PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(
    BookID ASC
 )
)
GO

/******Object: Table*****/
CREATE TABLE MembersList(
    MemberID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    MemberLName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    MemberFName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    MemberAddress varchar(50) NULL,
    MemberCity varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    MemberState char(2) NOT NULL,
    MemberZipCode varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    MemberPhone varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    MemberEmail varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_MembersList PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(
    MemberID ASC
 )
)
GO
```

I'm confused on how I would create these tables in the same way? Since they both depend on the other tables and the information thats already in them. I've looked around and found **Join** statements, but none of them were used in a way that would help me with this problem.

Comment: You should start out with the less dependent tables i.e tables with no foreign keys, regarding joins this is for querying data and not creating tables.

Comment: @MozartAlKhateeb Do you mean I should first add the data to the tables I've already created, Then create these two tables? Because The tables I create in my code posted above don't have any foreign keys

Comment: @Morph you can create all your tables before inserting any data.

Comment: @Morph As stated by others, you are confusing data manipulation with data definition, First create the tables, then insert the rows.  I think this confusion comes from lack of knowledge in how relational databases work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should be the order to create tables.

1. BookList
2. MemeberList
3. Book Issued
4. VendorList
5. InvoiceList
6. InvoiceItems

Invoice list shoul be created in last as it have references to vendor and invoice items and BookIssues should be created after MemberList and Book List

Comment: Shouldn't InvoiceItems be last? It has the foreign key here, which is the primary key of InvoiceList

Comment: Oh yes sorry ! I didn't see that. I have updated my answer